# java linked list works except in one instance

Tags: java, unicode, junit

I am writing a Linked List in Java that is essentially a mixture of Java's String and StringBuilder classes. I have to test it with JUnit and all of the tests pass, except for the last two, where it passes in a string consisting of every character. In this case the Linked List contains only the first two characters, but has the right length. I am not sure why it doesn't work in this case, but works in other cases where "abcd", "xyzzy", or "This is a very long string." I am not allowed to use string methods except for charAt() in the constructor. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class LString{

```
  private char letter;
  private LString next;
  private int length;

  public LString(){
  }
  public LString(String original){ //this constructor is where it fails
        if (original != ""){
              Scanner darkly = new Scanner(original).useDelimiter("");
              this.letter = darkly.next().charAt(0);
              this.next = new LString(); 
              LString curr = this.next;
              this.length++;
              while (darkly.hasNext()){
                    curr.next = new LString();
                    curr.letter = darkly.next().charAt(0);
                    curr = curr.next;
                    this.length++;
              }  
        }               
  }
  public int length(){
        return this.length;
  }
  public String toString(){
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        if (this.letter != '\u0000'){
              temp.append(this.letter);
        }
        LString curr = next;
        for (int j = 0; j < this.length; j++){
               if (curr != null && curr.letter != '\u0000'){
                     temp.append(curr.letter);
                     curr = curr.next;
               }
        }     
        return temp.toString();
  }
  public int compareTo(LString anotherLString){
        LString curr = this;
        LString test = anotherLString;
        if (this == null || anotherLString == null){
              return 0;
        }
        for (int q = 0; q <= this.length && q <= anotherLString.length; q++){
              if (curr.letter != test.letter){
                    return curr.letter - test.letter;
              }
              if (curr.next != null && test.next != null){
                    curr = curr.next;
                    test = test.next;
              }
        }
        if (this.length != anotherLString.length){
              return this.length - anotherLString.length;
        }
        return 0;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == null || !(other instanceof LString))
              return false;
        else {
              LString otherLString = (LString)other;
              if (compareTo(otherLString) == 0){
                    return true;
              }else{
                    return false;
              }
        }
  }
  public char charAt(int index){
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.length){
              throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        LString curr = findIndex(index, this);
        return curr.letter;
  }
  public void setCharAt(int index, char ch){
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.length){
              throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        LString curr = findIndex(index, this);
        curr.letter = ch;      
  }
  private LString findIndex(int index, LString search){
        LString curr = search;
        for (int l = 0; l < index; l++){
              curr = curr.next;
        }
        return curr;
  }
  public LString substring(int start, int end){
        if (start > end || start < 0 || end > this.length){
              throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        if (start == end){
              return new LString();
        }
        LString curr = new LString(Character.toString(this.charAt(start)));
        int p = start + 1;
        while (p < end){
              LString pete = new LString(Character.toString(this.charAt(p)));
              append(curr, pete);
              p++;
        }
        return curr;
  }
  public LString replace(int start, int end, LString LStr){
        if (start > end || start < 0 || end > this.length){
              throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        LString roger = new LString(LStr.toString());
        if (LStr == null || LStr.letter == '\u0000'){
              replaceHelper(roger);
              return this;
        }

        if (this == null || this.letter == '\u0000'){
              replaceHelper(roger);
              return this;
        }
        if (start == end){  
              if (this.length == 1 && start == 0){
                    LString temp = new LString(LStr.toString() + this.letter);
                    replaceHelper(temp);
                    return this;
              }else if (this.length == 1){
                    LString temp9 = new LString(this.letter + LStr.toString());
                    replaceHelper(temp9);
                    return this;      
              }
              if (end == this.length){
                    LString karl = new LString(this.toString() + roger.toString());
                    replaceHelper(karl);
                    return this;
              }
              if (end < this.length && start != 0){
                    LString ned = findIndex(start - 1, this);
                    LString pup = findIndex(end, this);
                    String batman = "";
                    while (pup.letter != '\u0000'){
                          batman += pup.letter;
                          pup = pup.next;
                    }
                    ned.next = null;
                    LString miranda = new LString(batman);
                    LString urkel = new LString(this.toString() + roger.toString() + miranda.toString());
                    replaceHelper(urkel);
                    return this;
              }
              LString jeff = new LString(roger.toString() + this.toString());
              replaceHelper(jeff);
              return this;
        }
        if (this.length == 1){
              LString temp11 = new LString(LStr.toString());
              replaceHelper(temp11); 
              return this;            
        }
        if (start == 0){
              if (end < this.length){
                    LString patrick = findIndex(end, this);
                    String themaxxxx = "";
                    while (patrick.letter != '\u0000'){
                          themaxxxx += patrick.letter;
                          patrick = patrick.next;
                    }
                    LString boudreau = new LString(themaxxxx);
                    LString yusef = new LString(roger.toString() + boudreau);
                    replaceHelper(yusef);
                    return this;
              }
              LString irvine = findIndex(end, this);
              LString geronimo = new LString(roger.toString() + irvine);
              replaceHelper(geronimo);
              return this;
        }
        LString jurgen = findIndex(start - 1, this);
        LString howard = findIndex(end, this);
        jurgen.next = null;
        String spawn = "";
        while (howard.letter != '\u0000'){
              spawn += howard.letter;
              howard = howard.next;
        }
        LString orion = new LString(spawn);
        LString bonnie = new LString(this.toString() + roger.toString() + orion.toString());
        replaceHelper(bonnie);
        return this;
  }
  private void append(LString curr, LString pete){
        LString yup = curr;
        while (yup.next.next != null){
              yup = yup.next;
        }
        yup.next = pete;
        curr.length++;
  }
  private void replaceHelper(LString help){
        this.letter = help.charAt(0);
        this.length = 1;
        this.next = new LString();
        LString result = this.next;
        for (int t = 1; t < help.length; t++){
                result.letter = help.charAt(t);
                result.next = new LString();
                result = result.next;
                this.length++;
        }      
  }
```

}
and here is the relevant testing code:

```
 private String allCharsString;

  @Before public void setUp() {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(((int)Character.MAX_VALUE) + 10);
     sb.append("}>");
     for (char ch = Character.MIN_VALUE; ch < Character.MIN_SURROGATE; ch++)
        sb.append(ch);
     sb.append("<{");
     allCharsString = sb.toString();
  }

  @Test public void test81aAllChars() {
     LString testLString = new LString(allCharsString);
     assertEquals("Problem with representing all chars",
           allCharsString, testLString.toString());
  }

  @Test public void test81bAllCharsLength() {
     LString testLString = new LString(allCharsString);
     assertEquals("Problem with representing all chars",
           allCharsString.length(), testLString.length());
  }

  @Test public void test81cAllCharReplace() {
     LString testLString = new LString(allCharsString);
     LString testLString2 = new LString(allCharsString);
     int length = allCharsString.length();
     assertEquals("Problem with representing all chars",
           allCharsString + allCharsString,
           testLString.replace(length, length, testLString2).toString());
  }
```

The first and third test fail, but the second passes. Here is the output:

```
Running special tests (3 tests)
Starting tests: E.E
Time: 0.131

There were 2 failures:
1) test81aAllChars(LStringTest$LStringSpecialTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: Problem with representing all chars expected:<}>[
!!(everycharacter goes here, in unicode)!! but was:<}>[]>
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringSpecialTest.test81aAllChars(LStringTest.java:764)
        ... 10 more
2) test81cAllCharReplace(LStringTest$LStringSpecialTest)
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: Problem with representing all chars expected:<}>[
!!(every character goes here, in unicode)!! but was:<}>[]>
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at LStringTest$LStringSpecialTest.test81cAllCharReplace(LStringTest.java:778)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I've looked at your test81aAllChars() test. testLString.toString = "}>" and its length = 2. Looks like you need to step through your toString() method. Throw in some print statements for your other failing test to narrow that one down too.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish in your constructor? Create a duplicate of the incoming parameter?

Comment: The constructor is supposed to take the input string and create connecting LStrings (my object) that each have a char data field with the letters of the string in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the real problem, and it has to do with character encoding. I verified that your constructor is good and length = 55300 after the linked list is created. I then stepped into your overridden toString() method. The third iteration through the for loop fails.....curr.letter IS equal to \u0000. This causes you to bypass the innards of the loop where you point to the next node, so the value of curr does not change after the third iteration. You simply iterate another 55297 or so times through the loop and do nothing. That's why the return value of toString is that little 2-character string "}>". I'm not an expert on charAt() and unicode, but I'm guessing that the third letter in your original string is encoded such that the first complete token the scanner recognizes is '\u1000'.

And that is why your second test passes. Your length counter got incremented properly, but it's really only a counter of how many times your constructor loop executed. When you get length from toString(), you get the value 2.

As a friendly design hint, toString() should use the following loop condition since a linked list is involved:

```
while(curr != null)
{
    //loop body
}
```

That way if something went wrong during list creation, you'd catch it more readily. Using this.length as a loop condition assumes your list length and counter are equal, which is a risky assumption.

Here's a working constructor:

```
public LString(String original){ 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (original != ""){
        Scanner darkly = new Scanner(original).useDelimiter("");
        LString currNode = this;
        while (darkly.hasNext()){
            currNode.letter = darkly.next().charAt(0);
            this.length++;
            if (darkly.hasNext()) { //don't add next node if no more chars
                currNode.next = new LString();
                currNode = currNode.next;
            }
        }
    }               
}
```

And here's a working toString() that loops the linked list  while ignoring specific character values as an exit condition

```
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
    temp.append(this.letter); //assumes you always have at least one character to print
    LString curr = next;
    while (curr != null ){
        temp.append(curr.letter);
        curr = curr.next;
    }

    return temp.toString();
}
```

I verified that this will get JUnit test test81aAllChars to pass. Didn't have time to look at your replace method and why that fails but maybe what I discovered here will help you in that one too. Good luck.

Comment: I completely agree. The problem is that this is for an assignment and I am only allowed to have this one LString class. There is another test, 81b that checks the length of the input string (allChars) and my LString object length, but that test passes. So even though the actual length of my object is 2, the length gets incremented to the right number. So, within these confines I am not sure how to fix my problem.

Comment: That's a good point about the loop in the toString method, I changed that. However, I did some print statements in the constructor and the this object only contained the two characters. In other parts of the code their had been broken links between this and this.next, but in this case it apparently works. However, this.next.next, which should be the third object in the list, is null. And I cannot figure out why that is. So the problem has to be in the constructor I believe, because before the toString() method is even called, the error is occuring.

Comment: I traced your constructor through about the first 70 loops. It works fine. Once I got past the first 20 characters or so, where the problem seemed to be, it was working as it should. The first 70 characters are: }>(bunch of non-printable characters)!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABC. The third character is being read in as Unicode 0. That's the problem. That's what causes toString() to spin after 3 iterations.

Comment: Just to confirm, I assigned the char value each time through the loop in the constructor to an int value. As I thought, you're reading in 0,1,2,....to start your constructor

Comment: Was thinking about the linked list traversal. I think your problem is solved if your loop condition in toString() is simply "while(curr != null)". Do you really even care what the next letter is? Seems to me that as long as you've got a non-null next node, you've got a letter to append to your StringBuilder, and its value is unimportant. This way, you're not relying on a char value to exit your loop, but rather just the fact that you finally got the the last node (because its next node is null).

Comment: I played around and found out indeed that the third character was null which was messing up in my toString() function when it said if (curr.letter != 'u0000'). So thank you for helping me figure this out that was an enormous help

Comment: Exactly my same thought process. I had to change the declaration of the next node at the top to next node = null; otherwise it did not see next as null even if it was. After that it worked perfectly, now I am just optimizing code.